# UICollectionView Horizontal Sticky Headers

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, horizontal-scrolling, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I'm implementing a UICollectionView with a set of sections and I scroll the items horizontally. I was to accomplished this but I having a hard time adding a Section header on top of the items. I tried to add a Section Header accessory but it was added before the first item (not on top).

This [link](https://gist.github.com/evadne/4544569) provides a way to create a horizontal sticky header, but still not on top of the items.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.